# A question about unitary block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For $n,m \in \mathbb N$, let $M_{n,m}(\mathbb C)$ denote the set of complex $n \times m$ matrices and put $M_{n}(\mathbb C):=M_{n,n}(\mathbb C)$. For matrices $A \in M_{n}(\mathbb C), B \in M_{n,m}(\mathbb C), C \in M_{m,n}(\mathbb C)$ and $D \in M_{m}(\mathbb C)$, we define the matrix $P \in M_{m+n}(\mathbb C)$ as
$$P : = \begin{pmatrix}A &B \\
C & D
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Give a necessary and sufficient condition that $P$ is unitary.

My attempt:
We can find that $$P^* =  \begin{pmatrix}\overline{A^T} &\overline{C^T} \\
\overline{B^T} & \overline{D^T}
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Therefore, $P$ is unitary iff $PP*=I_{m+n}$ ($I$ is the identity matrix) iff
$$\begin{pmatrix}A\overline{A^T} +B\overline{B^T}&A\overline{C^T} +B\overline{D^T}\\
C\overline{A^T}+D\overline{B^T} &C\overline{C^T}+ D\overline{D^T}
\end{pmatrix} = I_{m+n}.$$
Then we end up with 
$$A\overline{A^T} +B\overline{B^T}= I_n, A\overline{C^T} +B\overline{D^T}=0_{n,m}, C\overline{A^T}+D\overline{B^T} =0_{m,n}, C\overline{C^T}+ D\overline{D^T}=I_m$$
is the necessary and sufficient condition that $P$ is unitary. Is that a final answer? Can we find another better or more explicit answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed a final answer. This may be simplified a little bit more because the second and third equations are actually equivalent (take the transpose and the conjugate). These condition can be written in a nicer form using the notation $A^*$ for the transpose of $\overline A$.

Comment: How can I go on to prove that A and D are unitary matrices and that B = C ?

Comment: How can I go on to prove that A and D are unitary matrices and that B = C, given that P is unitary matrix??

Comment: @DavideGiraudo If you have a chance please look at [my post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2320128/implications-of-unitary-matrix-with-sub-blocks-of-matrices) and proposed answer on a similar type topic .

Answer (score 0):

I will try to complete the answer, mostly answering the follow-up question [Rakesh Adhikesavan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/217217/rakesh-adhikesavan) asked [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237746/a-question-about-unitary-block-matrix#comment2905305_1238101).

Indeed if we consider $A,B,C,D\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ with block matrix $P$ being $n\times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{C}$, or equivalently $2n \times 2n$ matrix over $\mathbb{R}$. Viewed this way one can obtain following nice relationships. First the way you represent $\mathbb{C^n}$ as $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ forces $A=D, B=-C$.

I will use as a definition the fact that $U$ is unitary if and only if $U U^* = I$.  Then by standart block matrix multiplication we obtain the following:

$$A A^T + B B^T = I$$
$$AB^T = B^T A$$